# JFrame background image. "absolute path in a file system"

Tags: java, image, swing, embedded-resource

I am creating a GUI using WindowBuilder in Eclipse and I searched for ways on how to add background images. Some suggested the use of a `JLabel`. There is an option in for labels called icon and I can set that to an image in an "absolute path in a file system" however this option gives a warning to never use in real application. I think this is because the program cannot find the image if the app is opened in another PC.

How can I add an image that can be used in a deployed application?

Comment: You can include the image as a resource within the application, which will include it within the Jar file when you export the program.  You can load these (embedded) resources using `Class#getResource`

Comment: Add it to the jar and access it as an [tag:embedded-resource]. An embedded resource must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.  Pretty much as suggested by @MadProgrammer ;)

Comment: *"Some suggested the use of a `JLabel`. There is an option in for labels called icon and I can set that to an image.."*  That is one way of doing it, but it has (at east) a couple of disadvantages. 1) The label will only account for the size of its own icon (and text).  IT will not get larger as more components are added on top of it. 2) The image does not resize with the GUI. - Both problems can be solved by using a custom panel to paint the image.